# Is safe to have a client id without secret to use in web apps?

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2, oauth2client

The only way that I found to not expose client secret on Front end was to create a client id without secret.

Is safe to have a client id without secret to use in web apps?

Answer (score 1):

You use the Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) which generates a secret at runtime. There is no need to configure a secret in the Authorization Server - you just set a client id.

See these resources of mine for more info:

- [Messages - steps 4 and 8](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/)
- [Tutorial](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/)